# Which synonym can I use for the word "desired" in this context?

Tags: synonyms

Which synonym can I use for the word "desired" in this context?

> The monitoring component is the visible interface which the consumers interact with to visualize the **desired** route location.

Comment: I suggest "required, necessary ".

Comment: I voted to reopen this question because I don't think the synonyms of *desire* given by a dictionary (*want, wish for, long for, yearn for, crave, hanker after, be desperate for, be bent on, covet, aspire to; fancy*) even in their past participle forms would fit the OP's sentence.

Comment: @DamkerngT. You're looking at desire synonyms instead of desired. http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/desired However,  I think this is a mistake that a learner could easily make so I'll vote to reopen. I would like to see a little more explanation in the question of why choosing a synonym is difficult/wanted, but I think newer users should be cut some slack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a synonym per se, in my opinion, but if I understand your intended meaning correctly, you could use this word:

> **[optimal](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/optimal)** (or *optimum*)
>   <sup>adjective</sup>
>   best or most suitable within a range of possibilities

Other possible words came to mind are *ideal*, *suitable*, *favorable*, or simply *best*.

Another note: I think your sentence would sound better without the word *location*, and I would use *user interface* rather than *visible interface*, and maybe *users* instead of *consumers*. Thus,

> *The monitoring component is the user interface which the users interact with to visualize **the optimal routes***.